# Minifilter and IRP_MJ_DIRECTORY_CONTROL post op

Tags: wdk, minifilter

I'm trying to intercept calls to `FindFirstFile/ZwQueryDirectoryFile` from a specific application from Minifilter. The goal is for the application to see a folder that doesn't exist. So if the app enumerates files and folders from an empty folder `C:\Temp`, that application shouldn't see that the folder is empty, instead it should see a folder in that directory (that I will provide in output result).

Now I understand that I need to modify [DirectoryBuffer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ifs/flt-parameters-for-irp-mj-directory-control) or `Mdl` buffer pointed by MdlAddress. Basically I need to return one more `FILE_BOTH_DIR_INFORMATION` structure instance to the caller. Problem is that those buffers comes with fixed size, so I can not add anything in them.

So my question is:

1. What options do I have. Should I allocate a larger memory from non-paged pool and replace the DirectoryBuffer pointer in post operation (same with Mdl)? Will the caller be able to access that memory?
2. If so, what should I do with original buffer, should I free it?
3. If not how can I return a larger buffer to the caller in user mode?

I'm lost, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to allocate allocate a larger memory.
If the memory has not space to add your file information, you just return STATUS_SUCCESS.
If it has free space, add your file information and return STATUS_NO_MORE_FILES.